# Posición eje x en ggplot2

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Estoy tratando de cambiar la posición del eje x de forma vertical, ya probé con

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

Pero no funciona

```
ggplot(tabla, aes(x = YY, y = Observado)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Ic_inf, ymax = Ic_sup), width = .2) +
  geom_line(aes(x = YY, y = Estimado)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1984, 2006, 1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.5, size = 8), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  legend.direction()
  theme_classic()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No pude reproducir el problema porque no tengo los datos. Sin embargo probaría ubicando la línea `theme_classic()` *antes* (arriba) de la línea con `theme()`. ¿Por qué? Porque `theme_classic()` es una especificación de tema completa para un gráfico. Al evaluarse después de tu especificación personalizada en `theme(axis.text.)` va a tener preeminencia. Digamos, "la sobreescribe".

Comment: Muchas gracias! Funcionó!

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que al añadir el "theme_classic()" al final estás reescribiendo el formato de gráfica que le antecede. Para solucionarlo te recomiendo agregar esta instrucción antes del formato que le das a la alineación del texto:

```
ggplot(tabla, aes(x = YY, y = Observado)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Ic_inf, ymax = Ic_sup), width = .2) +
  geom_line(aes(x = YY, y = Estimado)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1984, 2006, 1)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.5, size = 8), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```